# php to collect data from database

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to load a HTML form with data from my sql database. I use Zampp phpmyadmin

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = '';


$database="client";

mysql_connect(localhost,client);
@mysql_select_db($client) or die( "Unable to select database");
echo $query = "SELECT * $title,$service_number,$firstName,$LastName,$dob,$address,$postcode,$tel_number,$mob_number,$email,$partner_id ";
$result = mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();
?>
```

What do I have wrong?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: And please look at how SQL select statements are written, nothing like you've written yours: you haven't specified a table name; you're specifying "all columns" (*), then giving a long list of undefined variables.... even a basic bit of reading should tell you that this is wrong

Comment: first maybe better use PDO or mysqli, second what did you try with that query? :o

Comment: Do not suppress errors with the `@` sign! Don't use `mysql_` functions, but that has already been pointed out in detail. And do a decent PHP / SQL tutorial, because your query will never work that way. Also, `string` need to be encapsulated with quotes. And while you're at it, do some reading on SQL Injections. I'm sure you're not doing anything against that either.

Comment: btw i think this is the worst SQL query i ever saw here. Why people doesnt learn at least basic stuff before posting question here?

Answer (score 3):

1. `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_`
2. Do not suppress errors using `@`; use error handlers (ie. `mysql_error`)
3. You're not selecting from any table or any columns
4. You do not fetch your result set after executing the query
5. Passing variables into a query without binded parameters leaves you open to SQL injection

**Sample use of `mysqli_`**

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

[See the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\show.php on line 111

Comment: @pitbull10 Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn't structured well. You need to specify the table name from which the records should be selected. For example, you should be doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tblname`
```

That will select **all** fields for each record in the table. You can specify specific fields by including them (without the `*` wildcard) as follows:

```
SELECT `title`, `service_number` FROM `tblname`
```

You should be advised though that the `mysql_*` set of functions are deprecated now, and you should be using either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

You should also be sure to escape the variables that you're passing in. Your code is wide open to SQL injection in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

You're query is all wrong. Proper `SELECT` query is such:

```
SELECT fields FROM table;
SELECT * FROM table;
```

You are using PHP variables in your query (`$title,$service_number...`) which, in the code provided, does not exist. You need to fix your query.

Note: it's `fields` OR `*`, not both. Also, don't use MySQL_*, it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi_* or PDO

Answer (score 0):

this should get you going

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=client';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title,service_number,FirstName,LastName,dob,address,postcode,te‌l_number,mob_number,email,partner_id FROM client_table");
$sql->execute();
$results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $r){
var_dump($r);
}
```

Comment: If you took this from a website it's copied content. Please cite the source.

Comment: dsn taken from php.net pdo docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php other lines typed in by hand

Comment: <?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=client';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn,$title,$service_number,$FirstName,$LastName,$dob,$address,$postcode,$tel_number,$mob_number,$email,$partner_id);

$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM client");
$sql->execute();
$results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $r){
var_dump($r);
} 
?>

Comment: edited answer to name fields you want to get